# condition in Angular to check the number of characters in Angular

Tags: angular

I would like that the user enters only 10 characters in the input.
Below, the code works !

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="otp" maxlength="10">
```

Except that, I would like to get an error message: For example -> `Max 10 characters long.`

I think that, I have to create a condition in my HTML via Angular?
I have the impression that a few things are missing in my input?

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="otp" maxlength="10">
   <div *ngIf="?????.maxlength">
      Max 10 characters long.
  </div>
```

Comment: first you need to remove the maxlength in the input so the user can actually enter more than 10 characters. in the ngif, check the otp.length > 10

Comment: otp is a simple string, so you just have to test its length : `*ngIf="otp.length > 10"`

Comment: Optional: [Angular Reactive Form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many ways to do that, but a simple and quick way to do this without changing the current implementation is:

```
 <div *ngIf="otp.length > 10">
      Max 10 characters long.
  </div>
```

Also, you should remove the maxlength directive. You should disable the submission until users passes all the validation. If your form contains more fields and validation, you should use reactive forms and create multiple complex validation.